# I am having errors with my Unity collision script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, collision

I'm trying to make a collision script for my game where when the player hits an obstacle, the movement script is disabled. So, I tried to make a separate script for the collisions, but when the player hit an obstacle, the movement script was still active. So, I tried to modify the original movement script, but then I got a bunch of errors.

Here's the code I used:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementAndJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    float forwardForce = 500f;
    float jumpForce = 2000f;
    public BoxCollider collision;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("w") && collisionInfo.collider.tag = "Ground")
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) 
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.Tag == "Obstacle") 
        {
        MovementAndJump.Enabled = false;
        }
}
}
```

Here's the errors I got:

- "The namespace '' already contain a definition for 'MovementAndJump'
- "Type 'MovementAndJump' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types"
- "Type 'MovementAndJump' already defines a member called 'Update' with the same parameter types"
  Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you have two scripts of the same name

Comment: I checked and I don't think I have two scripts of the same name.

Comment: But that seems like the only logical answer I think.

Comment: Oh wait I do have two scripts with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Change `MovementAndJump.Enabled = false` to `this.Enabled = false`

That should fix it.

Comment: I think "this,Enabled" is JavaScript (maybe probably not), I'm using C#

Comment: Also, this problem has been fixed, thanks for helping though!